# NuGet install/update extremely slow in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I have a self made NuGet package, and when I try to make use of that package in a client solution, the install/update is really, really slow.

The NuGet Package comprises 250 files in 5 libraries, and has 10 dependencies on other packages.

The client solution have 7 projects using the package.

Updating the package in the client solution takes 5-10 minutes per project, and frequently Visual Studio 2013 crashes in the process. 
So when I make the smallest change to the package, it takes at least an hour before I am able to test it in the client.

I have tried Solution Package Manager and Console Package Manager with the same result. The -IgnoreDependencies argument also made no difference.

The package is not in source control.

Is my package too big, does it have too many files or libraries? Is NuGet only for small projects? I have not been able to find any other references to this problem, so any suggestions are welcome!